# Where can I contact the shipping department of VFS - New York scanning hub?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global, shipping

I applied for a UK standard visitor visa.

**I sent my application myself using USPS with a return shipping label from USPS inside the package**. I was informed by VFS that they cannot send back my passport using USPS and I need to send a UPS return label. **I replied back to that email with a UPS shipping label**. My co-worker also applied for the same visa, had sent a USPS shipping label and she wrote a fresh email to the same email address as above and she received her passport today.

My tracking number on UPS says 'Label created' (which means they haven't even handed it UPS yet).

**Where can I contact someone/anyone from VFS to get an update ?**

More info:

I applied for a Standard Visitor's visa for the UK from the US. I am a permanent resident in the US. I had my biometrics appointment at the Application Support Center in San Fernando, California.